# Rookie Question: Require user to enter a valid directory in the terminal for input into Go program

Tags: go

Rookie Question: I'm trying to write a program that takes a directory that is entered into the terminal to perform a later action in the program on that directory. If the user does not enter a directory that exists, how do I get the program to keep asking the user to enter in a valid directory? The error I'm getting on this program is listed at the bottom. I originally tried the fmt.Scan() to get the user input, have now moved onto the bufio scanner, and am at a loss so figured I would ask the experts. **Much thanks for any help!**

package main

import (
"bufio"
"fmt"
"os"
)

````
    
fmt.Println("What file path would you like to search?")
    
input := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    for input.Scan() {
        text := input.Text()
        x, _ := os.Stat(text)
        if x.IsDir() {
            fmt.Println("Cool this is a directory")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Sorry, this is not a directory")
            continue

        }

    }
}```

Error:
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x48b465]
````

Answer (score 2):

You could capture the error on the os.Stat() function. The code snippet would look something like this

```
        x, err := os.Stat(text)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Re-enter a valid dir:")
            continue
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the output of the Scan method, and any errors that might have happened there.

According to [the documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner.Scan):

> Scan advances the Scanner to the next token, which will then be
> available  through the Bytes or Text method. It returns false when the
> scan stops, either  by reaching the end of the input or an error.
> After Scan returns false, the Err  method will return any error that
> occurred during scanning, except that if it  was io.EOF, Err will
> return nil. Scan panics if the split function returns too  many empty
> tokens without advancing the input. This is a common error mode for
> scanners.

So, try checking out the `Err()` method for any errors and checking the `input.Scan` call's return value.